# Passing an array to a blade component from blade html fle

Tags: php, laravel

I have this component

```
@foreach($property_names as $p)
    <h6 class="w-50">${{$title}}
        <b>
            @if(array_key_exists($p,$options))
               <span>{{$offer_options[$property_name]}} </span>
            @endif
        </b>
    </h6>
@endforeach
```

and the constructor

```
   public function __construct($title, array $options, array $property_names) {
        $this->options = $options;
        $this->property_names = $property_names;
        $this->title = $title;
    }
```

Here is the blade code?

```
<x-option title="price"
          :options="$offer_options"
          :property_names="['prop1','prop2']"> <---- HOW TO PASS AN ARRAY OF STRINGS HERE ? 
</x-option>
```

I am getting errro:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #2 [ <required> $property_names ]] in class App\View\Components\Option (View: .... offer.blade.php)
```

How to pass an array to **$property_names** from Blade?

Comment: what problems are you facing?

Comment: I am getting an erro

Comment: Looks like forcing it to be an array `__construct($title, array $options, array $property_names)` is causing that error. maybe it's a collection, not an array?

Comment: ```<?php $property_names = json_encode(['prop1','prop2']); ?>
<x-option title="price"
          :options="$offer_options"
          :property_names="$property_names"> <---- HOW TO PASS AN ARRAY OF STRINGS HERE ? 
</x-option>
``` like this? And don't give type to params in method